# What to do about water under interlocking floor?

Tags: floor, flooding

I started a load of laundry and apparently the drain tube had come out and it ran most of the water from the load onto the floor.. We have the interlocking floor tiles but there are gaps and in a couple areas I could hear water squishing under the floor as I walked on it. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

We had to remove the flooring as there was no easier way to prevent mold underthe flooring. Then run a dehumidifier until the floor no longer smells muggy and wet. then replace new flooring. That was our experience.

Comment: Seriously? Are they like a throwaway floor surface?

Comment: The water made them warp, and it was only in the water for an hour or two. They wouldn't have been able to be evened back out. It was just easier to replace it. That was the laminate flooring. I dont know about true hardwood, or what kind of flooring the above question was asking about.